# How to check if schema of two dataframes are same in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have dataframe df1 which has columns a, b, c, d with int, int, int, int as corresponding datatypes

I have dataframe df2 which has columns a, b, **e**, c, d with int, int, string, int, int as corresponding datatypes

I should be able to find whether these two dataframes hold same schemas or not, which in this case is not same. How do I do it in an easier way in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the map dtypes to sets and find the intersection or the difference

```
len(set(df.dtypes).difference(set(df1.dtypes)))==0
```

Comment: Say we have df with a, b, c, d with int, int, int, int. 
df1 with a, b, d, c with int, int, int, int. In this case you query will return true which in case should be false as column c and d are interchanged in df1. 
df.dtypes==df1.dtypes should work in such case.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.testing import assertSchemaEqual

assertSchemaEqual(df.schema, df2.schema)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.